# Error with dateTime: The given path's format is not supported

Tags: c#, .net

Using .NET and C# I am attempting to create a directory at the specified path of "" + DateTime.Now

Function Call:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("" + DateTime.Now);
```

However, I get this error message:

> System.NotSupportedException: "The given path's format is not
>   supported".

Why is this?

Comment: What did you expect that expression to return  ("" + DateTime.Now)?

Comment: If you told us why you think you need to create a directory with the current date and time as a name we may be able to help you. Right now we can't.

Answer (score 4):

There are various characters which are [not allowed in path names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). These include `:` and `/`.

`DateTime.Now.ToString()` returns a string such as `01/20/2020 16:49:35`, which contains both `/` and `:` characters.

Therefore the string returned by `DateTime.Now.ToString()` is not suitable for use as a file or directory name.

---

You will need to give `DateTime.Now.ToString` a format string, which tells it how to render the current time in a way which does not use `/` or `:` characters. You can find the list of formats on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), but you probably want something like:

```
string now = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
```

Which gives for example `20200120_164935`.

Comment: Not entirely true. You can pass a format string to the `ToString()` function to make it work.

Comment: @Jesse Well it is true, because I specifically said `DateTime.Now.ToString()`, not `DateTime.Now.ToString("some format")`. This is, after all, what the OP's calling (albeit indirectly)

Answer (score 1):

DateTime.Now gets a DateTime object which is set to the current date and time on the local computer.

When this is converted to a string it contains ":" and "/"s. Colons and slashes are not valid in file or path names. They are considered illegal and "dangerous".